# Https server with cpp-netlib

Tags: c++, https, boost-asio, cpp-netlib

How can one use cpp-netlib to implement a HTTPS-server?

- cpp-netlib can be used as a HTTP server (see [service selector](https://github.com/kaspervandenberg/https-tryout/blob/master/runServer.cxx), [handler](https://github.com/kaspervandenberg/https-tryout/blob/master/syncHttp401Handler.cxx) and [main](https://github.com/kaspervandenberg/https-tryout/blob/master/httpServer.cxx) in my example code).
- With boost::asio setting up a SSL connection is not too hard (see [my attempt at SSL](https://github.com/kaspervandenberg/https-tryout/blob/master/helloWorld.cxx)).
- cpp-netlib accepts a boost::asio::io_service via the options provided to the constructor ([cpp-netlib reference](http://cpp-netlib.org/0.10.1/reference/http_server.html#constructor))

The following questions stop me from combining asio SSL and cpp-netlib:

- Both SSL via asio and cpp-netlib use an [asio acceptor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/acceptor.html) that listens to a port (e.g. 80 or 443) and then a separate session for the actual connection.

  I assume that for HTTPS:

  1. You use the asio ssl acceptor
  2. Which instantiates a connection
  3. Then perform the SSL handshake over this connection, and finally
  4. Have cpp-netlib serve HTTP over this connection

  But how can I separate cpp-netlib's HTTP connection handler from the acceptor is uses?
- Or does one pass a io_service from the asio SSL connection?  If so, which one? Or are they all the same?
- Or is there a completely different route to take?

Comment: Unfortunately HTTPS is not yet supported in cpp-netlib.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most recent release of cpp-netlib contains a working example. You'll find it in cpp-netlib-0.11.1RC2/libs/network/example/http/ssl. The github files are there:
https://github.com/cpp-netlib/cpp-netlib/tree/0.11-devel/libs/network/example/http/ssl

You have to use an async_server.

Answer (score 8):

A long shot, but have you tried the following:

- `#define BOOST_NETWORK_ENABLE_HTTPS`
   before including the boost network http client.
- Make sure `OpenSSL` is in the compiler path.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm currently working on a different project.  When I have time, I'll try it.